# In predicate logic, can existential variables be used interchangeably?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

When doing a derivation in predicate logic, am I allowed to use two different existential variables interchangeably?

For instance, is $\forall xPx$ (or $∃xPx$)   equal to $\forall yPy(∃yPy)$? If I cannot directly mix the two, am I allowed to do a Existential Instantiation on the $\forall xPx$, make it into a $Pa$, and use Existential Generalization to change it to $\forall yPy$?

If this is not allowed, can someone explain why?

Comment: $(\exists x)(x \not = y)$ is satisfiable, but $(\exists x)(x \not = x)$ is not. The key point is that you can replace $x$ with any variable that is not already in the formula.

Comment: So one of my questions is, say I am doing a derivation, can I treat ∃xPx and ∃yPy as equal? As in can I use them interchangeably?

Comment: Looking at my comment, if $P(x) \equiv (x \not = y)$, the answer is "no". You do have to be slightly careful to only use variables that aren't already used in the formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\forall x \,Px\;$ means the same thing as $\,\forall y \,Py,\,$ just as $\,\exists x\, Px \,$ means the same thing as $\,\exists y \,Py$.

Variables are variables; there's no significance which variable you choose to quantify, but once chosen, you need to be consistent in it's use. E.g., $\forall x\, Py$ means very little, since $y$ is nothing more than a free variable that has nothing to do with the quantified $x$.

You can use *Universal* Instantiation on $\forall x\,Px$ to instantiate $Pa$, and then use *Universal* Generalization to later change that to $\forall y\, Py$.

You cannot, however, universally generalize from a constant that has *not* been universally instantiated.